# How to use the foreign key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following question: let's say we have a Chen-Notation 1:n and m:n.

So `1` has a primary key and `n` also, where do I type the foreign key ? in the `n` ?

And the second question is about m:n, both have a primary key, and I need 1 more table because it's `m:n`, do I type the both primary keys as foreign keys in the 3rd table?

Comment: Can you show your table designs so far.

Comment: @PeterSmith there aren't , teacher told use we are going to get an ER-Diagram.

Comment: @PeterSmith lets take this as an example https://i.stack.imgur.com/L93pY.png , lets just use the first one `User` `Sumbits` `Bid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example of a `1:n` relationship** : customers and orders

One customer may have several orders. In this situation, you want a column in the orders table with a foreign key that references the primary key of the customers table.

Sample DDL:

```
create table customers (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    email varchar(50)
);

create table orders (
    id int primary key
    price float,
    customer_id int foreign key references customer(id)
);
```

**Example of a `n:m` relationship** : books and authors

A book may be written by more than one author. An author may have written more than one book. You create a bridge table, also called junction table, called `books_authors`, to represent that relationship, and that contains foreign keys to the two other tables.

Sample:

```
create table books (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(50)
);

create table authors (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(50)
);

create table books_authors(
    book_id int foreign key references books(id),
    author_id int foreign key references authors(id),
    constraint pk_books_authors primary key(book_id, author_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> So 1 has a primary key and n also, where do I type the foreign key ? in the n ?

The foreign key lives in the n, because 1 can have many keys, but you can't have a field that holds multiple values, you need to have one value per field, so it's in the n.

> And the second question is about m:n, both have a primary key, and I need 1 more table because it's m:n, do I type the both primary keys as foreign keys in the 3rd table?

Yes, because that 3rd table in effect has a many-to-one relationship to both tables.

Comment: Can you take look at my comment, e.g. do I type the `UserID` also as foreign key in `Bid`